# Отслеживание нажатия правой кнопки мыши на объект Ursina

Tags: python, ursina

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши на Entity срабатывал print('правая кнопка'). В документации Ursina не нашел такой команды.

Comment: потому, что отслеживание нажатия мышкой на какой-либо `Entity` не встроено почти ни в один API, эту функцию нужно писать самому, например: вычислять направление вектора от камеры до курсора мыши и пускать в направлении этого вектора луч, до пересечения с каким-либо объектом, чтобы, собственно, вычислить, в какой объект метил пользователь

Comment: @zolars если зажать левую кнопку мыши на объекте 'Draggable' и двигать мышкой, он будет перемещаться в пространстве